# Add switch in UITableView cell in Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift3, cell, uiswitch

How can I embed a `UISwitch` programmatically in a tableView cell in Swift?
I'm doing it like that

```
let shareLocationSwitch = UISwitch()
cell.accessoryView = shareLocationSwitch
```

Comment: it is so simple and easy just create a variable as a UISwitch() and then call cell accesooryView with that
you don't need to do many stuff to get there the code is already inside the question.

Comment: i just edit the question.
thank you for your solutions.

Comment: why my question received -2  point, it was really simple and after i found a good solution i just send it and edit the question so no one get confuse.

Comment: is there any reason that i don't now about it ?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Here is way you can embed a `UISwitch` on a `UITableView` cell.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {        
                var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "yourcellIdentifire", for: indexPath) as! YourCellClass

                       //here is programatically switch make to the table view 
                        let switchView = UISwitch(frame: .zero)
                        switchView.setOn(false, animated: true)
                        switchView.tag = indexPath.row // for detect which row switch Changed
                        switchView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.switchChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
                        cell.accessoryView = switchView

               return cell
      }
```

here is switch call beck method

```
func switchChanged(_ sender : UISwitch!){

      print("table row switch Changed \(sender.tag)")
      print("The switch is \(sender.isOn ? "ON" : "OFF")")
}
```

> @LeoDabus `Great! explanation`.

**Note: if your `tableview` may have more than one `section` then You should create a CustomCell subclassing `UITableViewCell` and configure your `accessoryView` inside `UITableViewCell` `awakeFromNib` method instead of table view `cellForRowAt` method. When dequeuing the reusable `cell` cast it to your CustomCell [Here is sample from @LeoDabus](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l25wk7vq7zsm3zp/TableView%20SwitchSample.zip?dl=1)**

Comment: anyone explain me please why you give me down voted. please leave a comment

Comment: i accept your answer and did not give you a vote or take any vote from you

Comment: Not my down vote but probably because a tableview may have more than one section. You shouldn't use tag property for this

Comment: @LeoDabus Right! I prefer delegate. in this question that is off topic. anyway would you share me for detect each row switch event instant tag property

Comment: @NazmulHasan You should create a CustomCell subclassing  UITableViewCell and configure your accessoryView inside UITableViewCell  awakeFromNib method instead of UITableViewController cellForRowAt method. When dequeuing the reusable cell cast it to your CustomCell

Comment: @LeoDabus Great! that's  clean code. thank  you so much your help.

Comment: @NazmulHasan https://www.dropbox.com/s/l25wk7vq7zsm3zp/TableView%20SwitchSample.zip?dl=1

Comment: I have added sections to the sample so you can use as a reference in the future if needed https://www.dropbox.com/s/up4fp9plzyxtlii/TableView%20SwitchSample%202.zip?dl=1

Comment: Also look at this article it may be useful too .
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34971329/uiswitch-added-to-uitableviewcell-multiple-times-when-scrolling-uitableview-sw

Comment: Why not just use tableview.indexPath(for: sender.superview) in switchChanged

Answer (score 0):

if you update the array with 3 elements and refreshing the table using self.tableView.reloadData() (for example after 2 second) you can see that with Xcode13 the switch values will be swapped and the example doesn't work. I have similar issue with my App when Xcode has been released to 13. try this: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_1HuI_JFIYusNmsdyekGBWXsGznneiQ7/view?usp=sharing